# Get the subclass parameter types using reflection, but not the superclass ones

Tags: java, reflection, parameters

Suppose I have:

```
abstract class A{
  public void init(String name){
    //do whatever
  }
}
```

And then we have:

```
class B extends A{
  public void init(String name,String lastName){
     super.init(name);
    //do whatever
  }
}
```

I would like to get the parameter types of class B, but when I do:

```
Class clazz= classLoader.loadClass("B");
for (Method m : clazz.getDeclaredMethods())
     {
        if(m.getName().equals("init")){
           Class<?>[] parameters = m.getParameterTypes();
           for(Class<?> param : parameters){
             print(param.getSimpleName())
           }
      }
     }
```

I get 3 parameters, the ones of class B and the one of class A .....(??)
What I would like to get is only the parameter types for class B.

Is there a way to not query the superclass?

Comment: Shouldn't B extend A?

Comment: yes i forgot it, added now

Comment: use 'm.getDeclaringClass()' for checking that

Comment: You should only get the parameters of B.init. I think that you either have an overload of the method or you're not looking at the right class.

Answer (score 0):

From [JavaDoc of `Class.getDeclaredMethods()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods--):

> Returns an array containing Method objects reflecting all the declared methods of the class or interface represented by this Class object, including public, protected, default (package) access, and private methods, **but excluding inherited methods**.

This is exactly what I'm experiencing when executing your code. So I doubt that your iteration also includes inherited methods. Please check/debug again.